# C: freeRTOS does not work as expected

Tags: c, scheduler, freertos

I write a simple example including 2 tasks: task 1 and task 2. Task 1 has the higher priority than task 2. In task 1 function, I increase the priority of task 2 so that its priority is equal to (**task 1's priority + 1**). Moreover, in task 2 function, I decrease its priority by 2 so that it has the lower priority than task 1.
As a result, the execution sequence is as task 1 -> task 2 -> task 1 -> task 2 ...
However, when I run my code, task 2 runs first. May anyone help me to address this issue? I include my code and the result as follows:

```
/* Standard includes. */
#include <stdio.h>

/* Kernel includes. */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "basic_io.h"

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
#define mainDELAY_LOOP_COUNT            ( 0xffffff )
/*
 * The tasks as described in the comments at the top of this file.
 */
static void prvTask1( void *pvParameters );
static void prvTask2( void *pvParameters );

/*
 * The task parameters
 */
const char *pvTask1Param = "Continuous task 1 is running\n";
const char *pvTask2Param = "Continuous task 2 is running\n";

xTaskHandle xTask1Handle, xTask2Handle;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

void main( void )
{

        /* Start the two tasks as described in the comments at the top of this
        file. */
        xTaskCreate( prvTask1,                  /* The function that implements the task. */
                    "Task 1",                   /* The text name assigned to the task - for debug only as it is not used by the kernel. */
                    100,                        /* The size of the stack to allocate to the task. */
                    (void*)pvTask1Param,        /* The parameter passed to the task - just to check the functionality. */
                    2,                          /* The priority assigned to the task. */
                    &xTask1Handle );            /* The task handle is not required, so NULL is passed. */

        xTaskCreate( prvTask2, "Task 2", 100, (void*)pvTask2Param, 1, &xTask2Handle );

        /* Start the tasks and timer running. */
        vTaskStartScheduler();

    /* If all is well, the scheduler will now be running, and the following
    line will never be reached.  If the following line does execute, then
    there was insufficient FreeRTOS heap memory available for the idle and/or
    timer tasks to be created.  See the memory management section on the
    FreeRTOS web site for more details. */
    for( ;; );
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

static void prvTask1( void *pvParameters )
{
    char *string = (char*)pvParameters;
    for( ;; )
    {
        vPrintString(string);

        portBASE_TYPE task1Priority = uxTaskPriorityGet(NULL);
        vTaskPrioritySet(xTask2Handle, task1Priority+1);
    }
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

static void prvTask2( void *pvParameters )
{
    char *string = (char*)pvParameters;
    for( ;; )
    {
        vPrintString(string);

        portBASE_TYPE task2Priority = uxTaskPriorityGet(NULL);
        vTaskPrioritySet(NULL, task2Priority-2);
    }
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyR3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running this in the [FreeRTOS Windows port](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Windows-Simulator-Emulator-for-Visual-Studio-and-Eclipse-MingW.html) using FreeRTOS V8.2.3, and the output shows task 1 running first, which I think is as expected:

```
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
Continuous task 1 is running
Continuous task 2 is running
```

Comment: Which compiler do you employ?
My instructor builded this file with WATCOM C/C++ and ran the executable file but the result is that task 2 still ran first. I ultilized Eclipse IDE for C and C++ Developers and it didnt worked as expected.